# fgetc() function to read the whole file

Tags: php, fgetc

I'm trying to read the whole file using fgetc() with a do..while loop. I know this is not recommended but it should work. The contents of counter.dat are **i dont know whta to do** but the ouput that I'm getting is **0**. Why 0?

```
<?php
 $f = "counter.dat";
 if (!($fp = fopen($f,"r"))) {
      die("Can Not Open $f");
 }
 do {
  $one_char = fgetc($fp);
  $counter = $one_char;
  $counter .= $one_char;
 } while($one_char);
 fclose($fp);
 $counter = (int) $counter;
 echo $counter;
?>
```

Comment: You're throwing away the previous value of `$counter` when you do `$counter = $one_char;`. Get rid of that line.

Comment: @Barmar. I did as you said but then it gives an error that says undefined counter on line 12.

Comment: Because you never initialized `$counter`.

Comment: what are the contains of counter.dat

Comment: @RonakDhoot. counter.dat contains the sentence, "i don't know what to do"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overwriting `$counter` each time through the loop, before you append to it. And on the last iteration, `$one_char` will be `FALSE`, so you're setting `$counter = FALSE;`, and converting that to an integer returns `0`.

You also need to initialize `$counter` to an empty string at the beginning.

Since the file doesn't contain an integer, you shouldn't use `(int) $counter`. Just print the value of `$counter`.

Do it like this:

```
$counter = "";
while ($one_char = fgetc($fp)) {
    $counter .= $one_char;
}
echo $counter;
```

This exits the loop immediately when it gets to EOF, it won't try to use the `FALSE` value from the last iteration.

Comment: I copied your code and pasted it there. 0 is Still the output.

Comment: Does the file contain a number?

Comment: No. Just a single sentence, which is, "I don't know what to do".

Comment: Why are you trying to convert that to an integer with `(int) $counter`?

Comment: oh. that was the problem. i removed that and it worked. please edit your answer so that I can select it as answer. Thank you for your help.